# Accessing list of dictionaries in template by index

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of dictionaries in the django template. I wish to use its values in a form.

```
[
{
    "movie_id": 1950,
    "title": "In the Heat of the Night (1967)"
},
{
    "movie_id": 3741,
    "title": "Badlands (1973)"
},
{
    "movie_id": 3959,
    "title": "Time Machine, The (1960)"
},
{
    "movie_id": 4101,
    "title": "Dogs in Space (1987)"
},
{
    "movie_id": 8572,
    "title": "Littlest Rebel, The (1935)"
},
{
    "movie_id": 65230,
    "title": "Marley & Me (2008)"
},
{
    "movie_id": 105954,
    "title": "All Is Lost (2013)"
}
```

]

In my template, I want to get values of each field by index. ie. for the 
list[0]['movieId'], I would like to get the value 1950. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it via `dot (.)` notation.

From the documentation

> Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup
> - Attribute or method lookup
> - Numeric index lookup

So you can use `list.0.movieId`. The `0` dot attribute will access the list element and `movieId` will do the dictionary lookup.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, man. Will check out the docs more thoroughly regarding this.